# Fishpig Wordpress Magento integration no longer working

Tags: fishpig

Since I upgraded to the latest Fishpig Wordpress version for Magento the extension no longer works?

If I go to Wordpress >> in the menu in Magento I get redirected to the settings page with the error: Unable to login. Check your WordPress Admin login details below.

I am 100% sure these credentials are correct and if i re-add them on the settings page and save it saves successfully!

Before installing the upgrade I used to be able to go directly to the wordpress admin but now if i try and go to any of the wordpress pages directly all I get is a blank/white screen?

Answer (score 0):

If the auto-login system isn't working, you should always first try and login to your WordPress Admin directly. This allows you to check that the details you have are correct and that your WordPress Admin is functioning correctly.

To access your WordPress Admin, just add /wp-admin/ to the URL that WordPress is installed on.

You mention in your answer that if you go to any WordPress page directly, you get a blank white screen. This sounds like you have a fatal PHP error that is being supressed. If this is the case, this is 100% definitely the problem as Magento cannot automatically login to WordPress if WordPress isn't working.

To fix this, enable PHP errors by adding the following code to your WordPress Admin index.php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Next, go to your WordPress Admin by adding /wp-admin/index.php to the URL that WordPress is installed on. If the error isn't displayed on screen, open up the HTML source, scroll to the bottom and you should find the error there. It's impossible to know what the error could be but fixing this should be your first priority.

After fixing this if the auto-login still isn't working, upgrade WordPress to the latest version.